# If we are opening a door does the distance of the hand from the pivot influence how much of moment will be lost just to press the pivot?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, momentum, torque, equilibrium

If we are opening a door does the distance of the hand from the pivot influence how much of moment will be lost just in an useless press of the pivot? Is it correct thinking that as far from the hinge we press the door much of the moment will be spent in moving(rotating) the door but as we are pressing nearer to the hinge there will be more mass of the door far from both our hand and the pivot and so there would be more equilibrium in inertia between this part of the door and the part near the pivot both divided by the point where your hand is positioned and is pressing the door? That would cause more resistivity against rotation.... So should in that case the pivot feel more pressing instead the whole door feels just an useful rotating force of our hand so at the end our action of rotating the door will be less efficient?

Comment: downvoted because the sentences are unclear, i.e. the use of physics terms.  Please rewrite the question using usual physics terminology. e.g moment = force x distance to try and make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

To open the door with a constant angular acceleration say $\alpha$ we need a constant torque.However the force required to produce this torque varies as the perpendicular  distance of line of action of force from pivot point varies.

Since ,

$$\tau =F \times l$$

where F is Force , and l is perpendicular  distance of line of action of force from pivot point.

So more the distance less the force and vice versa.